# How to make a "Real-Time Responsive"？

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TextBox and a DataGridView. When the user presses types some words inside the TextBox, the DataGridView should immediately show the result from db (bound to the DataGridView)

Question: How to make the TextBox "On Real Response"?

I mean if I type "Hello", and during the processing of inputting each letter into the TextBox, each time I have to do a new search, the UI form must be dead because there are too many requests to the db. I know that I can use threads, however what I really want is that there's a mechanism that can allow me to cancel or accept the "Search From db and bind to the dataGridView".

In detail, that is:

Each time when I change the TextBox's value, there comes a request with the value from textbox and do search from db, and the previous TextBox's value can be cancelled instead of doing the previous search in a background-thread, etc.

Does the .NET framework have such a mechanism now? Or **someone can suggest good ideas about cancelling the previous query string to be searched for or during the searching process? Can anyone show me a demo with persudo codes**

Comment: your probably using the event `textchanged` try using the event `keydown` or `keyup` then filter it to search once the user press `enter key`.

Comment: Sounds like a combination of using a separate thread to handle the database queries while leaving the UI responsive, cancelling queries as (not) needed, and using a combination of the `TextChanged` event as suggested by Saechel and a time delay as suggested by jmcilhinney so that a fast typist doesn't cause too much thrashing.

Comment: @Saechel: I already thought of that, but that doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: You should take a look at Rx. Its pretty much built for this problem. Here is a tutorial for WPF (which works much better with Rx, and to be frank if you are just starting out, you shouldn't be learning a dead technology like WinForms anyway) http://blog.petegoo.com/2011/11/22/building-an-auto-complete-control-with-reactive-extensions-rx/

Comment: @Aron: Many thanks! And I'll see that.

Comment: @Aron: If possible, you can delete your comment and post directly as an answer, I'll mark yours, yours really helps me.

Comment: This question has been clear and solved by @Aron. I don't know why you think that not clear? Don't you like WinForm or some specific reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cancel a previous query then you call `Cancel` on the `DbCommand` object that executed the query.  Why don't you know that already, given that it's right there in the documentation?

That said, I tend to use a `Timer` to delay the query by a short period.  That way, no query is executed until the user pauses their typing.

Comment: +1 for the timer. Just set it to about 500 milliseconds (or whatever feels right), and reset it OnTextChanged. When it fires, query the db.

Comment: @jmcilhinney:How to use that with a Timer? The question is when a user is inputting, maybe he/she is pressing keys very quickly, if I handle TextChanged event, a lot of events will be raised.

Comment: Yay to reinventing the square wheel!

Comment: `Stop` and `Start` the `Timer` in the `TextChanged` event handler, initiate the search in the `Tick` event handler.